# One step YouTrack "Fixed in build" filling with TeamCity integration

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I am using TeamCity Professional 8.1 and YouTrack 5.0.6.

I have managed to fill "Fixed in build" field in YouTrack with two step workflow.

1. I am using **#issue-id Fixed** command in my Merucrial commit message to change the state of issue in YouTrack.
2. I made some changes in code ( not related to fixed issue) and I push changes to the server.

When TeamCity finishes the build with changes from the second step it fills the "Fixed in build" field of my issue with the build number.

But the issue was actually fixed in the previous build...

So I want to be able to fill the "Fixed in build" field right in the first build that includes the command to change the state of the issue to Fixed.

Is this possible?

Edit: **I have fixed my issue by changed the issue prefix from number "1" to my project name "csv".**

Answer (score 0):

Please uncheck 'Process Resolved Issues' option in mapping dialog and make sure time on TC and YT is in sync -- if YT decides a build was created before the issue was fixed, it will not set it into fixed in build.

Comment: TC shows in _Administration/Diagnostics/Internal Properties_ **user.timezone=Europe/Prague**  and
YT shows in _Settings/Visual/Default timezone_ **Europe/Prague**  
I hope that it means the time is in sync?

Comment: Time on both machines should be in sync as well. Did you try unchecking the 'Process Resolved Issues' option?

Comment: TC and YT are running on the same machine. If I uncheck the 'Process Resolved Issues' then 'Fixed in Build' is never filled.

Comment: This means you have not set up the integration correctly from the TC side. Please add YT as an issue tracker there.

Comment: Integration from TC side is set up OK. YT is set as an issue tracker and YT is pulling changes ( based on Hg commit messages ) and placing them into TeamCity changes tab in the corresponding issue.

Comment: Pulling changes is fine, but this only means that the integration from YT side works fine. Please make sure TC shows fixed issues on Issues tab of a build.

Comment: The Issue Log tab is empty. But YT is set up as an issue tracker in TC and Test connection from TC for issue id is working fine...

Comment: Make sure you have listed Project Ids when configuring issue tracker in TC.